# How to choose a couple exactly 7?

Tags: probability

There are 10 married couples.  How many ways could they form 10 couples for a dance, if everybody danced with someone of the opposite sex and exactly 7 married couples danced together?

I came up with it below.  But what should I do after that?
$${10 \choose 7}{3 \choose 3}$$

Sorry, I forgot important information for the first sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start (as you did) by choosing which pre-existing couples will dance together.  There are $\binom{10}{7}$ ways to make this choice.

Now, you are left with three men and three women, and you need to match them up in such a way that no married couple dance together.  This is what's called a *derangement*: you can think of it as a permutation that has no fixed points.  In this case, you want a derangement of size $3$.

Given that $3$ is a small number, at this point you could easily just list all of them out: say that your men are $m_1,m_2,m_3$, and your women are $w_1,w_2,w_3$, where $m_i$ and $w_i$ are married.  Can you list out all ways to arrange these into three pairs such that $m_1$ doesn't get paired with $w_1$, $m_2$ doesn't get paired with $w_2$, and $m_3$ doesn't get paired with $w_3$?

Comment: I made a list, and I got 3 pattans.

Comment: Then something has gone wrong -- there should only be two.  What patterns did you come up with?

Comment: oh, when I was writing my list, I noticed my mistake.  It is only 2 patterns.  Thanks.